# Eclipse crashes on MacBook M1

Tags: eclipse, apple-m1

I've recently moved from Mac with Intel to Mac with M1 and I have to use Eclipse, but it doesn't work on M1. What happens is that Eclipse opens up, asks for directory for workspace, main windows shows up. In bottom right corner it says, "deferred early start" and after that "setup check". This check goes to 20% and then Eclipse crashes. I tried to reinstall it, but same result.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest Eclipse. If this doesn't help, tell the exact Eclipse and Java version and other things that may cause it not to work for you but for everyone else.

Comment: I have Eclipse version 4.19 and Java openjdk 11.0.11 (at least that is what i get after writing "java --version to terminal), I don't know if there is anything that could produce this problem because laptop is new.

Comment: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565690

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to run eclipse on apple M1.

1. Running eclipse for intel architecture using rosetta translator(requires jdk as well as eclipse to be of x86_64 architecture)
2. Running eclipse built for apple M1 with a jvm for aarch64

In the first case you can use 4.19 build. In general eclipse should work, but there can be some problems

In the second case there is a build available from 4.20 onwards at [eclipse-SDK-4.20-macosx-cocoa-aarch64.dmg](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.20-202106111600/download.php?dropFile=eclipse-SDK-4.20-macosx-cocoa-aarch64.dmg). This will require a jvm for apple M1.

With [JEP 391: macOS/AArch64 Port](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/391) targeted for Java 17, you should be able download jvm for apple m1

Comment: The link to the eclipse SDK no longer seems to work I'm afraid. However, I did find 4.22 RC1 for the same platform :-)